# Convert string time to normal time value replacing the hour to the correct

Tags: c#, datetime, time, hour

I have the following example string values:

```
24:05 , 25:08 , 26:59
```

and I need a function or something else to get a correct time value (hh:mm) like:

```
00:05 , 01:08 , 02:59
```

Is there a method in C# that does this?

Please help me, I gonna to be crazy on this!!

Thx!
Cheers..
Alessandro

Answer (score 3):

With regex you can do it like this:

```
var match = Regex.Match("25:05", @"^(\d{2,}):(\d{2})$");
var hour = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) % 24;
var min = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);

// hour will be 1 and min 5
```

If you like to avoid regular expressions then a simple `input.IndexOf()` and `input.SubString()` will do it.

*Update:* If you want a method for it, then take a look at this:

```
static TimeSpan ParseHHMM(string input)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(input, @"^(\d{2,}):(\d{2})$");
    var hour = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) % 24;
    var min = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);

    return new TimeSpan(hour, min, 0);
}

// Write to console
Console.WriteLine(ParseHHMM("25:05").ToString(@"hh\:mm"));
```

*Update:* I've changed `\d{2}` to `\d{2,}` for the hour part. This means it now can take an input like `125:05`.

Comment: It's exactly what I want. Yuo're great! Thx lasseespeholt..Thank you very much

Comment: To be flexible, the pattern should be `(\d+):(\d{2})` so as to match 3:05, 3:00 123:01, etc.  One could argue that it ought to be flexible WRT to the minutes as well, but not many people represent time as H:M, usually it will be H:MM at the very least.

Comment: @Nicholas I've assumed 3:05 would be written as 03:05 but yes, `\d+` would fix that :)